# Derivations on a quotient field K of a integral domain R

Tags: abstract-algebra

A derivation $D: R \to R $ is a additive homomorphism satisifying 
$$D(xy)=yDx + xDy$$
Let $K$ be the quotient field of $R$ , I want to show the derivation can be extended to $K$ such that the quotient law is well-defined
$$ D(\frac{x}{y})=\frac{yDx-xDy}{y^2}$$

Here is what I got so far

Assume $\frac{x_1}{y_1}=\frac{x_2}{y_2}$, since R is an integral domain, one has $x_1y_2-x_2y_1=0$, so that 
$$ y_2Dx_1+x_1Dy_2-y_1Dx_2-x_2Dy_1=0$$
We need to show $$y_1y_2^2Dx_1-x_1y_2^2Dy_1-y_1^2y_2Dx_2+x_2y_1^2Dy_2=0$$
which is derived from the derivative of the quotients.
I don't know how to connect those formulas. Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: multiply the first formula by $y_1y_2$ and use $x_1y_2=x_2y_1$